# PHP PDO Class Data Extraction

Tags: php, pdo

Hello so I am currently using a PDO Class that I've downloaded in [this](http://www.imavex.com/php-pdo-wrapper-class/) website and this is my code of selecting all the data `$results = $db->select("accounts");`. And here is the functions in the class

```
public function run($sql, $bind="") {
    $this->sql = trim($sql);z
    $this->bind = $this->cleanup($bind);
    $this->error = "";

    try {
        $pdostmt = $this->prepare($this->sql);
        if($pdostmt->execute($this->bind) !== false) {
            if(preg_match("/^(" . implode("|", array("select", "describe", "pragma")) . ") /i", $this->sql))
                return $pdostmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            elseif(preg_match("/^(" . implode("|", array("delete", "insert", "update")) . ") /i", $this->sql))
                return $pdostmt->rowCount();
        }   
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();    
        $this->debug();
        return false;
    }
}

public function select($table, $where="", $bind="", $fields="*") {
    $sql = "SELECT " . $fields . " FROM " . $table;
    if(!empty($where))
        $sql .= " WHERE " . $where;
    $sql .= ";";
    return $this->run($sql, $bind);
}
```

My problem is I want to echo out the data in a while loop but I'm having problems doing it. For now I am using `print_r($results)` to check the data in my database. I've tried

```
while($row=$results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{ echo $row['Somefield']; }
```

and I am getting this error. `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object` . How can I put that code in a while or foreach loop?

Comment: Where is your query???

Comment: show the code where you assigning value to `$results`

Comment: @saty have you checked the pdo class?

Comment: @Sourabh have you checked the pdo class?

Comment: Please post your code here instead of providing external link

Comment: Looking through the class, `$db->select()` returns the result of a `PDOStatement::fetchAll()`. This means that you should iterate over `$results` with: `foreach ($results as $result) { echo $result['Somefield']; }`.

Comment: @saty there you go boss

Comment: @Phylogenesis Thanks. Solved, will mark your answer as best if you can comment it again and using foreach instead of for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment above, the wrapped PDO class makes a `PDOStatement::fetchAll()` call and returns the result of that from `db::select()`.

As such, you need to iterate over `$results` as you would any other array:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result['Somefield'];
}
```

Comment: As a continuation, can I just use if($results >0) { echo "Login success"; } with that?

Comment: @FewFlyBy You can do `if (count($results) > 0) { echo "Login success"; }`.